# List in Views of nodes connected via entity reference

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I have nodes that are linked to each other like a chain, i.e. node A is referenced to node B, node B is referenced to node C, node C to node D etc etc. So, there is only one level.

What I want to do is on the page for each given node, display all the nodes earlier in the chain and all the nodes later in the chain. For example, if I'm viewing the page node C, then I want to list the preceeding nodes A and B in one View, and the succeeding nodes C and D etc in another node.

Thanks.